# How to develop with Stack two separate but related packages?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm writing a library and a project that uses the library. It's common with Stack to put both in the same folder and maintain a multi-package project, but I want to have two separate projects instead. Stack has external dependencies for this, but they are specified by locations and the projects runs on multiple machines, so it's inconvenient to specify paths (unless it's possible to have nested Stack projects, but this kinds defeats the purpose of having separate packages). I also don't want to use git locations, because it feels burdensome to explicitly specify commits (or maybe this is not necessary?), and don't want to pack the repository in an archive and then download it each time I change something.

Ideally, I would like to be able to install the library on a machine and then reference it somehow in `stack.yaml` by its name, not location. Is it possible to do that? If not, is there a convenient way to maintain two separate but related packages?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Stack, but have you considered git submodules?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thanks, "submodule" is a term I needed. It [seems](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/348) people indeed use them with Stack for this kind of a task. Still, I'd prefer to reference the library by its name.

Comment: Sounds a bit like you want a private hackage. [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/5eo2w3/question_solution_for_a_private_package_repo/)'s a recent discussion on that and related approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using git submodules as [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) suggested. Works good so far.